# Getting a list of transitions for all workflows in an object's workflow chain

Tags: workflow, plone

I have an object with two workflows.

```
obj.portal_workflow.getTransitionsFor(obj)
```

returns only transitions from the primary workflow.

I've written the following code to get a list of all possible transitions for all items in a list.

How am I doing?

```
transitions = []
for i, obj in enumerate(self.items):
    for w in workflow.getWorkflowsFor(obj):
        for tid,t in w.transitions.items():
            if w.isActionSupported(obj, tid):
                if t not in transitions:
                    transitions.append(t)
return transitions
```

Campbell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I see in the getTransitionsFor source code, it must returns you all transition for all workflows.

http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/Products.CMFPlone/tags/4.1/Products/CMFPlone/WorkflowTool.py

Comment: Too right.  This nagged at me horribly until yesterday when I came to have another look, and getTransitionsFor() was suddenly shiny.  I have a feeling that someone's fixed some incorrect guards or permissions since then, although my python should have accounted for those..  Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work just fine.  But you may want to consider using the method already available in @keul's answer.